# how to test tooltip function value using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="icon_png information icon_baggageyes" title="getTooltip()"></div>
```

in here toot tip given by getTooltip() function. is there any possible way to get function return value for testing using selenium

Comment: Are you able to find the text on HTML which is showing on tool-tip. If yes then share that HTML code too

Comment: no.. is show as above html code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("YOur Xpth Of over code"));
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

Put a `String source = driver.getPageSource();` and then save that source somewhere (or print it to console)

Take a look at the page source, to see what element has the tooltip text in it, and then you can write a selector for it.

Hope it will help you